# Mathematical equation to link pages

Tags: php, algorithm, math, graph-theory

It's kind mathematics query..I want a script in php that will do following

Let's say I've 100 pages page1.php, page2.php, page3.php, page4.php....goes on page100.php

I want to create a php algorithm to link each page with one another. Each page will have 10 page links to other pages but I want a mathematical equation that will link each page.

page1 will have 10 links to other pages, page2 will have 10 links to other pages, this will go on until each page is equally linked in total 100 pages with one another.

Comment: say what?   can you explain a bit better what you want to do?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?  To figure out how to make "jump to page" links (i.e., on page 10 you would see 1,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,100)?  Or are you trying to do some strange search-engine optimization?

Comment: @Maniator, @Justin, just I want to use it for internal page linking within the same site site.

Comment: @malic. why do you have so many php pages. why dont you utilize php's $_GET method. ill post in answer below

Comment: if the order is not relevant, you can link each page to the following 10 pages. (1 will go to 2..11, 2 will go to 3..12, etc). each page will get 10 links that way

Comment: Is this some kind of SEO scheme? :-)

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky, yep order is not relevant.

Comment: @divideandconquer.se How are footer links an SEO scheme?

Answer (score 3):

One simple way would be to link to the previous- and next-five pages, wrapping around from 100:

- 1 links to 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
- 2 links to 97, 98, 99, 100, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
- ...
- 100 links to 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Every page gets linked to exactly 10 times (from the exact pages it links to itself)

---

Of course, instead of doing something strange like this, perhaps you should consider simply improving your UI?  For instance, having a dropdown, or even better a search-box, for users to find what they are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

why do you have so many php pages. why dont you utilize php's $_GET method.

instead of: page1.php, page2.php, page3.php, page4.php....goes on page100.php

your users would goto: content.php?page=1, content.php?page=2,content.php?page=3...

and in the content.php page you can have an array of pages:

```
$pages = array (1,2,3,4,...)
```

and then:

```
if(in_array($_GET['page'], $pages){
    //do stuff for whatever page is set
}
```

and then on the bottom of each page you can output all the pages you have:

```
shuffle($pages); //put pages in a random order
$count = 0;
foreach($pages as $page){
    echo "<a href='content.php?page=$page'>Page $page</a>";
    if($count < 10){
        $count++;
    }
    else break;
}
```

Comment: That would display 100 links in the footer. I think he just wants 10.

Comment: you don't even have to do the URI variable portion, as apache can do URL reqriting...

Comment: @malic - is it correct? because if one of the answers is correct, on stackoverflow you shpuld select one of them as correct, that way if you have future questions people would see you looked at answers to your questions :-)

Comment: IMO, random footer links to sequential pages seems completely useless; however, without seeing the actual content...it might be valid ;)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to manitor's answer, but only showing 10 pages in the neighborhood of the current page.

```
define("TOTAL_PAGES", 100);
define("FOOTER_LINK_COUNT", 10);
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

// Range check
if ( $page < 1 || $page > TOTAL_PAGES ) {
  $page = 1;
}

// You can display a header here if you'd like

// Include actual content page
include("page{$page}.php");

// Generate the footer    
echo "<ul>\n";
for (
  // Maths! Start at the current page, minus half of the total number of links to display
  // but don't go below 0 (negative pages) and don't go over the total number of pages
  $i = min(
    max(0, $page - ceil(FOOTER_LINK_COUNT / 2)),
    TOTAL_PAGES - FOOTER_LINK_COUNT
  ), 
  $c = 1; 
  $c <= FOOTER_LINK_COUNT;
  ++$c ) {
  printf("\t<li><a href='?page=%1\$d'>%1\$d</a></li>\n", $i + $c);
}

echo "</ul>";
```

So for page 1, you see 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

For page 10: 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15

For page 95: 91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100